# Modes of Motion of A Lennard-Jones Cluster

Tags: homework-and-exercises, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics, normal-modes

I am trying to analyse the dynamics of a cluster of 79 atoms. The context of the question is that each atom in the cluster (which has Lennard-Jones interactions between the atoms) is displaced by a small amount and allowed to vibrate about it's equilibrium, generating a large number of modes of motion (rotational, translational, vibrational etc.).

The system can be described with:
$$\omega^2 \vec{x} = \tilde{D}\vec{x}$$
Where $\omega^2$ (the eigenvalues) are the squares of the vibration frequencies for each mode of motion, $\tilde{D}$ is the "dynamical matrix" which is a $3N\times3N$ (N = 79) square matrix, and $\vec{x}$ are the eigenvectors of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11}  \\ x_{12}  \\ x_{13} \\ x_{21} \\ x_{22} \\ x_{23} \\ \vdots \\ x_{237, 3}  \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $(x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{13})$ correspond to the cartesian coordinates of the amplitudes of the first atom.

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are all calculated numerically and the initial equilibrium positions of the atoms are known. Based on this I must identify which of the first 10 eigenvectors correspond to translation, rotational and vibrational modes, as well as the directions of translation, the axes of rotation and the nature of the vibrational modes.

Identifying which eigenvector is which is not difficult, the translational modes show repeating values in the eigenvector for each atom eg. $(2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, \dots etc.$). The rotational modes have no effect on the position of the central atom therefore the first 3 values of the eigenvector are $(0,0,0)$. The remaining modes then must be vibrational.

I also know how to derive the direction of translation however I am stuck on how to find the axis of rotation and what kinds of deductions I can make about the vibrational modes. I would appreciate some help on these fronts, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first step for the analysis of the normal modes is to properly identify the symmetry of your cluster. A good starting point is to evaluate the moment of inertia tensor for the cluster (using well-converged equilibrium positions). Then, the three orthogonal eigenvectors provide three candidates for the rotational axes. Once the maximally symmetric axis has been identified, it should be quite simple to identify the point group of the equilibrium configuration.

Arrived at this point, the classification of the normal modes can be done by classifying each normal mode according to the irreducible representations of the point symmetry group.